# Retrieving Nested Referral Data in CakePHP 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to figure out how it's possible to get the value of a nested child object in CakePHP 3.x

A basic example consists of three entities:

Server, Rack, Operating_System

Tables:

Racks - id, name

Servers - id, hostname, rack_id, operating_system_id

Operating_systems - id, name

Rack hasMany Servers

Server belongsTo OperatingSystems & belongsTo Racks

How can I reference Rack->Server->OperatingSystem->name in my Rack View?

```
//View.ctp
<?php foreach ($rack->servers as $servers):
echo h($servers->hostname) 
echo h($servers->operating_system->name)   //Doesn't output OS Name
endforeach; ?>

//View Function in RacksController:
public function view($id = null)
{
    $rack = $this->Racks->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Servers']
    ]);
    $this->set('rack', $rack);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['rack']);
}
```

Not sure if this ends up being a custom query in the controller or if there is a built-in Cake syntax to accomplish what I need.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer:

[Cake 3.x passing-conditions-to-contain](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#passing-conditions-to-contain)

```
$rack = $this->Racks->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Servers','Servers.OperatingSystems']
    ]);
```

Solution is to use the dot notation for deeply nested associations.  Thanks to aknd for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$rack = $this->Racks->get($id, [
    'contain' => ['Servers' => 'OperatingSystems']
]);
```

Comment: Hmm tried this in the controller, end up with: Error: Unsupported operand types

Comment: In @aknd's solution, you need to put `'OperatingSystems'` inside another array (i.e. `'contain' => ['Servers' => ['OperatingSystems']]`). That will resolve the "unsupported operand types" error and let you use the array notation, which can be clearer at times than the dot notation.